# Calculating covariance matrix of large arrays in Python giving Memory Error

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

I have an array of shape [128000,2], and want to calculate covariance matrix of it in Python [Mac OS, 8GB RAM, 64-bit]. I do actually have upto 10 columns but for simlicity just testing with 2 cols.

Using numpy.cov() is giving me either Memory error / the process gets killed after running about 5 min.

```
a = np.fromfile(filelocation,dtype=np.complex64) # length of 128000
b = np.fromfile(filelocation,dtype=np.complex64) # length of 128000

Q = np.vstack([a,b]).T
COV = np.cov(Q)
```

I have searched other similar questions on this site, where few suggested using memory map. But I am not getting clear, on how exactly I should be using mem map with covariance as an input.

It will be helpful if anyone can let me know how to exactly use memmap for this, or any better way for calculating the covariance of the arrays.

Comment: What is the expected size of C?

Comment: Why do you transpose `Q`? Don't you want a 2x2 covariance? Your code currently tries to compute a 128000x128000 matrix, no surprise it runs out of memory...

Comment: The expected size of COV is [128000 x 128000]

Comment: `128000 x 128000 x 8bytes / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 = 122 GB`. Buy some memory.

Comment: @Julien . I understand you suggestion. It is true that solving for large arrays like this will definite be easy when you have RAM. But is not it quite common for someone working with dataset which has million of rows ? Do they solve it with buying RAM ? There must be some algorithms that should solve the problem. As I mentioned one of them is memmap. But I do not understand how that works !

Comment: Different people will do different things depending on their different final goals and different resources...

Comment: If your question is 'how do I use memmap?' then read the memmap docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html

Comment: What are you doing with the covariance matrix once you calculate it?  It's possible to calculate in blocks, but only some follow-on operations will find this useful.

Comment: @DanielF, Once I compute the covariance matrix, I am willing to do singular value decomposition to find its eigenvalues eigenvector and variance. And use these values to generate some output.

Answer (score 0):

Can try batch learning (e.g. coded with *[tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709854/how-to-get-covariance-matrix-in-tensorflow) + keras*), having created Autoencoder layer within Neural Network designed according to your aims or see here [to your aim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51545659/reducing-calculation-time-and-requirements-for-large-covariance-matrix?rq=3)

But taking into consideration your task described in comments (for what you need covariance matrix), note that SVD is used in [sklearn.decomposition.PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) - with highly effective algorithm, no manual coding needed. If you still will lack memory try opportunities mentioned first in my answer- aka Neural Network of your own design (with Autoencoder layer)

Comment: Please read and apply [answer]. Additionally some punctuation might be beneficial.